# tar xvf with * failed on some platform like HP-UX or SuSE

Tags: tar, wildcards

`tar xvf archive.tar *.txt` failed on HP-UX and SuSE.

How can I extract only files matching `*.txt` for a tar archive ? 
I could use --wildcards on SuSE but this not work on HP-UX

I'm on HP-UX 11iv2 (11.23) on HP ia64 and SuSE SLES 11 update 3

Thanks

Comment: What version of HP-UX exactly?  **The argument is looking for a folder name not a filename.**  I use the command all the time with wildcards in order to compact everything in a folder.

Comment: It's HP-UX 11iV2 (11.23)

Comment: The real problem is tar can't manage filename with character "*". It seem it not specifically a GNU tar issue because I had same with GNU tar on SuSE SLES 11 update 3

Comment: Well I can't help since I am using an entirely different version of HP-UX then you are.

Comment: Does it work if you put `*.txt` in quotes, `tar xvf archive.tar '*.txt'`?

Comment: Thanks Adaephon, no it doesn't work even if I put `*.txt` in double quotes `"*.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

<s>how about:</s>

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs tar xvf archive.tar
```

I unfortunately don't have the machines to test this.

Edit: oops, that was dumb of me. Maybe this is better:

```
tar tf archive.tgz | grep '.txt$' | xargs tar xzf archive.tgz
```

Comment: `tar x` extracts, so having the exact same files around (which is needed to `find`) seems like a very special use case.

Answer (score 0):

`tar t` lists the archive's contents. So the following may work, assuming `bash` and no spaces in file paths:

```
tar xf archive.tar $( tar tf archive.tar | grep '.txt$' )
```

Non-recursive:

```
tar xf archive.tar $( tar tf archive.tar | grep '.txt$' | grep -v / )
```